# How do I reset BlueJ to default settings?

Tags: bluej

How can I reset BlueJ back to default settings? There doesn't seem to be a reset option anywhere in the preferences menu.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @Nurzhan Windows 10. Is the process different depending on the OS?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Just the paths will be different. How did you change the settings? Did you change the bluej.properties file?

Comment: @Nurzhan I've been using the preferences window. I wanted to reset my settings because BlueJ was acting strangely on my laptop. I want to try resetting my settings before I try a full reinstall.

Comment: I think, at them moment the easiest way is to reinstall bluej, but I might be wrong. Next time find the bluej.properties file on your system and make backup of it before you make changes to the editor.